# Обход CloudFlare

Tags: linux, безопасность, ip, site, cloudflare

Есть сайт, хочу попробовать узнать его ip, но он защищен CloudFlare, общие способы из инетрнетОВ устарели, либо не работают. Через почту ip спалить тоже не получается. Есть какие-то приземленные методы? Даже если нет, то как узнают ip в таком случае?

Answer (score 3):

Я прошу прощения за иронию, но Cloud Flare не зря берут свои деньги и вообще обеспечивают кеширование трафика приблизительно 30% интернета.

Если в настройке сайта не допущено ошибок - вы не узнаете ip стоящего за Cloud Flare сервера.

Самая явная ошибка, которую можно допустить при настройке - это подключить CF не сразу. Тогда интересующий Вас сайт некоторое время торчал в интернет со своего настоящего IP. Как узнать, было такое или нет, и какой был этот IP и не поменялся ли он - думайте сами.

Второй способ - это внимательно читать заголовки http ответов сервера и пытаться получить все server side variables - иногда при настройке nginx или другого прокси человек может допустить ошибку, и реальные адреса останутся в заголовках. Вероятность этого крайне мала, но попробовать можно.

Еще можно внимательно проанализировать все имеющиеся в dns записи в исследуемом домене. Может быть, что там остались "хвосты" от старых настроек, или технические записи типа beta.www.mysite.ru, которые указывают если не на конекретный ip, то на диапазон ip, которые можно просканировать в надежде, что один из них ответит как искомый сайт (для  того, чтобы это сканирование диапазона работало - опять таки, надо нарушить инструкции CF по настройке)

А вообще - скорее всего, узнав реальный ip вы получите ip, принадлежащий некотму провайдеру. За которым скрываются множество сайтов и серверов. Так себе занятие.

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ!

Comment: Если ответ Вам пригодился - Вы можете отметить его "галочкой" слева от ответа. Успехов!